# Making themed TK button have a border

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit, ttk

With the default theme on Linux, I can't get the button to have a border. Here's my attempt:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

tk = Tk()

style = Style()
style.configure('TButton.border', background='red')

button = Button(tk, text='Hello')
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

I have found theming very difficult because it is not clear what I can change. Sometimes changes seem to do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple proposal ... if you really want a border. Understand it should not be satisfactory.

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

def nothing(event=None):
    print "click"

bgbutton= tk.Button(root, )
bgbutton.pack()
bgbutton.configure(relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=5, background="#2244FF", activebackground="#FF0000", highlightcolor="#00FF00")
button= tk.Button(bgbutton, text="Glance at my border", command=nothing)
button.pack()

button.configure(relief=tk.GROOVE, borderwidth=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what theme you're using; not all themes associate all widgets with all the elements they might have, and some (e.g., the OSX native theme, `aqua`) really very tightly control what the look and feel of many elements are (since the theme engine in that case delegates to the native drawing code). It's entirely possible that the theme you're using just doesn't permit red borders at all.

Try switching to a different theme…

```
ttk.Style().theme_use('clam')
```

Comment: I tried all available themes but it didn't allow me to change the border. I think I am doing it wrong even if I need a certain theme.